# ListField and button focus issue in same screen

Tags: blackberry, button, listfield

Hello all i stuck at one problem. I have implemented a `ListField` in one Screen. On top of the Screen i have used one `HorizontalFieldManager` to hold a `TitleLabel and Two Butons`. I have pushed some screen on all the rows of the listfield. My problem is, letSuppose when i am on 4th row and i have selected what i want then when i clicking on the button, then the button worked but the screen which i have implemented at 4th row also appear how to avoid it. I am testing it on storm 9550 simulator and using Blackberry eclipse plugin5.0 . I am running out of idea please help me .

navigation click is like this

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

    selectListAndButton();
    return true;

}
```

//And here is the selectListAndButton Method

```
private selectListAndButton(){
 Field field = getFieldWithFocus().getLeafFieldWithFocus();
    if(field == backCustomButton){
        //Popped the active Screen

    }else if(field == saveCustomButton){
        //Saving some Data to the Database And pushing another Screen here
                    // problem comes here if i am at 2nd row of the listfield and selects  
                     something from there and clicked on the button the screen which was  

                     implemented at 2nd row also appears   

    }

    else if (_list.getSelectedIndex() == 0){    
        //Called a date picker

    }
            else if (_list.getSelectedIndex() == 1){    
        //Pushed some another screen 

    }

           else if (_list.getSelectedIndex() == ){  
        //Pushed some another screen 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved it. but posting the answer late. I just dropped the idea of using `ListField` because i dont have so much rows to add. So i have just used the little trick rather using `ListField` i have used `HorizontalFieldManager` and its look like a `List` so everything working fine.

Thanks cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onTouch` for `Screen` and call specific functionality depend on event coordinates and `Field` boundaries:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
   if (isTouchInside(message, saveCustomButton)) {
      save();
   } else {
      showNextScreen();
   }
}

private boolean isTouchInside(TouchEvent messages, Field field) {
   int eventCode = message.getEvent();       
   int touchX =  message.getX(1);
   int touchY =  message.getY(1);

   XYRect rect = field.getContentRect();

   return rect.contains(touchX, touchY);
}
```

Comment: what is `isTouchInside()` method do can you explore it a bit more and why its not working with `navigationclick`

Comment: touchEvent method will call navigationClick by default. They made it for compatibilities with old code. This works pretty OK, except you're overriding navigationClick method in your controls/screens. I didn't debug your code, but looks like touch event doesn't call onFocus for your Button or it's in UI thread queue and navigationClick processes before focus gain it.

Comment: ok as soon as it will work for me i will give a kudo to you and +1 for trying to explain me thanx...